# Model suggestion for estimating 6D pose of custom object

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

For a project of mine I’m trying to be able to track the 6D pose of a tennis racket. I’ve been looking for a model that I can use to to track either the pose or 3D keypoints of a custom object and I wanted to know if anyone had suggestions. One option I had been looking at was PoseCNN and training with synthetic data. I had also heard about pose lifting to get 3D pose from 2D keypoints generated from another model but could not find much information on it.